# Reading specific word from xml

Tags: batch-file

I have the following **batch script** to read an xml file and find a word (in this case, "***factory***"):

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"factory" xcsconfig.xml') do set content=%%a
set content=%content:*"=%
set content=%content:~0,-1%
echo %content%
exit /b
```

Here's part of the **xml** file:

```
   <loggers>
      <recorder1>
         <add name="factory" value="xlog"/>
         <add name="alias" value="WSEnterprise.log"/>
      </recorder1>
      <recorder2>
         <add name="factory" value="weblog"/>
      </recorder2>
   </loggers>
```

The code works fine and will always return the "first" founding - *value="weblog"/*.  My question is, is there a way to return the founding under a specific tab? (i.e. I want to search specific under **recorder1** instead of **record2** tab, and return answer ***value="xlog"/***).   Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I changed my expected answer, it was incorrect

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But code of solution will be awful. Is it really necessary to do it in batch script? I highly recommend you to use something external (for example, python).

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I mistyped the expected answer, it's now changed.

Comment: @llya I would prefer batch since it will be execute on more than 100 remote desktop and it's a hazard to install python on each.  Also it is part of my larger program so it would be great if batch can achieve what is needed, thanks

Comment: would be quite easy, if you could be sure, the wanted line is always the first occurence of ´factory` (with your current code, you will get always the last occurence)

Comment: Thanks Stephan but that's only part of the xml file, and it will not be always the case you mention.  Thanks for the tips thou!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sectionstart=recorder1"
SET "insection="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type q25062317.txt') do (
 IF DEFINED insection (
  ECHO "%%a"|FINDSTR /c:"factory" >NUL
  IF NOT errorlevel 1 SET "content=%%a"
 )
 ECHO "%%a"|FINDSTR /i /L /c:"<%sectionstart%>" > NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET insection=Y
 ECHO "%%a"|FINDSTR /i /L /c:"</%sectionstart%>" > NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "insection="
)
set content=!content:*"=!
set content=!content:*"=!
set content=!content:~1,-1!
echo %content%
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25062317.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Comment: Thanks Magoo however it returns error (window prompt then disappear).  I tried both changing the q25062317.txt back to my xml file's name (doesn't work), and change my xml to q25062317.txt (doesn't work either).  I just copy and paste the block from your answer to my script.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Alex: the code works properly. Just replace the `goto` statement with a `pause` statement and test it.

Comment: Yea needed to pause it to see the result, embarrassed hah...  Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate also the next statements inside the `do` block of the `for` cycle. I mean:

> setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"factory" xcsconfig.xml') do (
>   set content=%%a
>   set content=!content:*"=!
>   set content=!content:~0,-1!
>   echo !content!
>   )

In this way the output is not only the last XML code line but all the code lines that contain the "factory" string in the file considered. Of course this example doesn't echo only a single desired string but this is possible setting a condition to the output of the loop.

Comment: @RodolfoCangiotti Thanks Rodolfo but it also returns error - window pops up and disappear

Comment: May I ask where did you replace % with ! ?  I tried doing it to the last echo statment but then it returns nothing on screen

Comment: I have supposed that you have added manually the `EnableDelayedExpansion` statement. Try it now and let me know; it should output all the the statement with the `factory` string.

Comment: Added setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion, still returns nothing on screen, only ECHO is on.  I also tried @ echo off at the very top, then it's only "press any key to cont..." from pause statment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a robust tool that can help you - the command looks like this to get the line you need and it can be wrapped in a `for /f` loop.

```
type file.xml |findrepl "<recorder1>" /e:"</recorder1>" /b:"factory"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `findrepl.bat` (by aacini) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/rfdldmcb6vwi9xc/findrepl.bat

Place `findrepl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or on the path.

Comment: Thanks Foxi the file download is bloced currently I will try to grab it later on a private computer.